# hide dropdown when something else is clicked except dropdown itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown on a website and i want to hide it when something else is clicked except the dropdown elements themselves. Right now what i have works with jquery but would love to have the same logic with vanilla javascript. i feel like my jquery logic is clunky, i have been thinking for a long time and i would love some input.
thank you so much.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.icon').length ) {
      $('.dropdown').css('top','30px');
      $('.dropdown').css('opacity','1');
    }else if ( ! $(e.target).closest('.icon').length && !$(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
      $('.dropdown').css('opacity','0');
      $('.dropdown').css('top','-530px');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I would suggest modifying classes instead of manually modifying the css in your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/dlizik/xeLbrnob/

```
(function(box, faded) {

    var elem = document.querySelector("."+box);

    var settings = { 
        elem: elem,
        classes: elem.className.split(" "),
        toggle: faded
    };    

    window.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

    function clickHandler(e) {
        if (e.target !== elem) modifyClass.call(settings, false);
        if (e.target == elem) modifyClass.call(settings, true);
    }

    function modifyClass(bool) {
        var index = this.classes.indexOf(this.toggle);
        if (bool === true && index > -1) this.classes.splice(index, 1);
        if (bool === false && index < 0) this.classes.push(this.toggle);
        this.elem.className = this.classes.join(" ");
    }    

})("box", "faded");
```